# Why doesn't product get added to cart in Carthrob?

Tags: cartthrob

A site running EE 3.5.7 and Carthrob 3.2

The site was moved from another domain and now I am not able to add items to the cart.

The item is sent to the product_detail page using:

```
<a href="{entry_id_path='/new/image'}">
```

On the product page I have the following code:

```
...
{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form
        class='form-horizontal'
        entry_id="{entry_id}"
        no_tax="{no_tax}"
        no_shipping = "{no_shipping}"
        return="{template_group}/view_cart"
    }

        
            {exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}"}
              {if dynamic}
              <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="{option_field}">{option_label}</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                    {input}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {if:else}
                    {if options_exist}
                  <div class="control-group">

                        <label class="control-label" for="{option_field}">{option_label}</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                        {select class="input-medium"}
                            <option {selected} value="{option_value}">
                                {option_name}{if option_price_numeric != 0} +{option_price}{/if}
                            </option>
                        {/select}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/if}
                {/if}
            {/exp:cartthrob:item_options}

        <div class="control-group">
        {if "{inventory}" == "0" }
            <p><strong>This item is out of stock</strong></p>
        {if:else}
            <label for="product_quantity" class="control-label">Quantity</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="product_quantity" class="input-medium"  placeholder='1' name="quantity" size="8"  />
            </div>
        {/if}
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
...
```

When I click **Add to Cart** it goes to view_cart but the I get the following message:

> Shopping Cart You have no items in your cart. Continue shopping.

I have reinstalled the default templates but to no avail.

Any help in getting this resolved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a cookie setting issue. I found it [here].[1](https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/pages/troubleshooting/index.html#add-to-cart-problems)